# Split values of a python dataframe into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split the values of the columns "words" and "frequency" into multiple rows of the dataframe `df`.

**[1]: Problem** https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i1p6.png

I use the following piece of code to manipulate the data:

```
df = (df.set_index(["document"]).apply(lambda x: x.str.split(",").explode()).reset_index())
```

The problem I have identified is that the values in column "words" and "frequency" are in brackets e.g. (word1, word2, word3, wordn). The output after execution of the code is NaN.

The following solution is sought:

**[2]: Solution:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQqo1.png

Answer (score 1):

you were close! The problem might be in the reset of indices... For a csv file looking like:

```
"document","words","frequency"
"document 1","(cat,dog,bird)","(12,34,354)" 
"document 2","(berlin,new_york,paris)","(1,13,254)"
```

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(",").explode())
df3 = df2.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace("(","").explode())
df4 = df3.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(")","").explode())
print(df4)
```

Maybe you can do it with only one function (not with a lambda one)

Comment: It does work... Maybe the issue is in your data format... I tried with the csv file that I added to my answer.